# python install setup.py FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory: __init__.py

Tags: python, m2crypto

in my project, I downloaded the lib named m2crypto,

[image]

I want to install it by `python ./libs/m2crypto/setup.py install`

but I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/markleo/Desktop/projects/test-proj/libs/m2crypto/setup.py", line 338, in <module>
    version=__get_version(),
  File "/Users/markleo/Desktop/projects/test-proj/libs/m2crypto/setup.py", line 319, in __get_version
    with open('src/M2Crypto/__init__.py') as init_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'src/M2Crypto/__init__.py'
```

but i do have the `__init__.py`.

[image]

---

I also tried to add below content to `libs/m2crypto/MANIFEST.in`

```
recursive-include src/M2Crypto/__init__.py
```

but still get this error when install setup.py.